# Export SQL Server Database to Access using entity framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, ado.net

Is it possible to export a sql server database (2008) to a new access database using the Entity framework (or anything else for that matter in code)?

I have developed a desktop facing application that connects to a sql sever on a server and my client wants to be able to take snapshots of the database in access to send to people who don't have sql or access to the sql server (as they can't do it manually).

This is being done in c# .NET 3.5 SP1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier if you can convince the user to use SQL CE instead. You should be able to create an adp database to use as the front end of the SQL CE database.
You can use Microsoft Sync Framework to sync data between databases.